# Can Not Open File in Loop C++

Tags: c++, file, loops

I have a c++ application which have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ALL_EPID_CERTS_LENGTH; i++)
            {
            std::ifstream file(; 
            file.open(path.append(ALL_EPID_CERTS_1_0[i]), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary); 
            if(file.is_open()) 
            {
                // get the length of the file 
                file.seekg(0, ios::end); 
                size_t fileSize = file.tellg(); 
                file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
                // create a vector to hold all the bytes in the file
                vector<byte> data(fileSize, 0);
                // read the file
                file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data[0]), fileSize);             
                byte *tempCerts = new byte[data.size()+1];
                memset(tempCerts,0,fileSize+1);
                std::copy(data.begin(), data.begin()+(data.size()), tempCerts);
                // !!!!check if NULL and place for NULL are needed
                for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++)
                {
                    list.push_back(tempCerts[j]);
                }
                file.close();
            }
            }
```

In the first iteration the loop does the expected, but since the second one - file.is_open() returns false.
All the files are existing.
Sould you explain me please what is wrong???

Comment: your code can not compile: `std::ifstream file(; ` is not valid c++ syntax

Comment: Not your question but why do you need `tempCerts`? `list.push_back(data[j]);` would work just as well.

Comment: _Guess_: `path` needs reconstructed instead of being continuously appended to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do `path.append` - what is `path`? What do you expect it to be after first iteration - is it ok that `ALL_EPID_CERTS_1_0[1]` is appended to `ALL_EPID_CERTS_1_0[0]`?

Comment: If it's `std::string`, then on the second iteration it'll contain concatenation of `ALL_EPID_CERTS_1_0[0]` and `ALL_EPID_CERTS_1_0[1]` and I don't think that's what is expected.

Comment: @john it appends inplace http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/

Comment: Yes my mistake, comment deleted.

Comment: In other words `path + ALL_EPID_CERTS_1_0[i]` not `path.append(ALL_EPID_CERTS_1_0[i])`

Comment: yea this is probably the problem

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call `infile.clear();` to clear the state bits after closing the stream, otherwise you can't open a new file with the same stream.

Also: Are you sure you need to append to the path at every iteration? Output your path variable after every append call and check if the paths are correct. I expect that at the second iteration the path string will look something like this: "c:/some/path/file1.txtfile2.txt"

In cases like this I would use a  `stringstream` or `sprintf` to generate the path, and make sure not to change the path variable.